# Rename [google-container-image] tag to [google-container-os]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The Google Container-VM Image product name has changed to [Container-Optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs).  For consistency, the tag [google-container-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-container-image) should be changed to [google-container-os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-container-os).  How can we rename the tag?

Comment: There are only 5 questions, so I retagged them all with [tag:container-optimized-os] ([max tag name length is 25](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)). Now we need a moderator to make the 2 tags synonyms.

Comment: I much prefer the OP's original proposal, google-container-os (length 19, so, no problem). It avoids the confusion that would be caused should any other company make a different "OS optimized for containers", and is much more aligned with many existing, popular tags such as google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-bigquery, and so on.

Comment: Yes, please use google-container-os for the reasons that Alex has mentioned.  Note that the old google-container-image wasn't exactly the lower-case equivalent of Google Container-VM Image, so it's OK that the word optimized is not included in google-container-os.

Comment: @AlexMartelli They're tagged [tag:google-container-os] now.

Comment: @approxiblue, great!